# In C#, although the variable is null in the code, it does not enter the else block

Tags: c#, if-statement

When my Database.defaultCard list is empty, it sends null into FirstOrDefault done (I know so). But when sending null value, it doesn't enter else block and An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ToDo_App.dll: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' I get an error. No matter what I did, it didn't go into the else block. How can I solve this or if there is something I need to know, can you write?

```
       string done = Database.defaultCard.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Line == "DONE").Line;
        if (done!=null)
        {
            ListingProgressNotNull(done);
        }
        else
        {
            done = "DONE";
            ListingProgressNull(done);
        }
```

Comment: You need to check if `Database.defaultCard` is null and do an appropriate action. You cannot call `FirstOrDefault` on `null`.

Comment: @PalleDue No the issue is that `FirstOrDefault` returns null and they try to deference that to get `Line`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `FirstOrDefault` returns `null`you are still trying to access the property `Line`. This causes the null exception.

Use the null conditional operator: `?.`

`string done = Database.defaultCard.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Line == "DONE")?.Line;`

If `defaultcard` can be null use it also there:

`string done = Database.defaultCard?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Line == "DONE")?.Line;`